# How to correctly form php tag within html

Tags: php

Hello I have a script like below:

```
<div id="contentLeft">
<ul>
    <?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){?>
        <li id="recordsArray_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['content']; ?></li>  
    <?php}?>
</ul>
</div>
```

But I get an error saying - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\drag\index.php on line 53

What have I done wrong?

Comment: what all these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Parse+error%3A+syntax+error%2C+unexpected+%24end did wrong too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blockquote  `<?php}?>`

Leave a space there. And try not to use this format....

```
 <?php } ?>
```

I think it is better to use this

```
<div id="contentLeft">
<ul>
<?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<li id="recordsArray_'.$row['id'].'>'.$row['content'].'</li> ';
        }
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I always do it like that to... I just don't get it why people are mixing php and html... you can't understand anything when you look at such a mess as in the question...

Answer (score 1):

Try the alternative syntax:

```
<div id="contentLeft">
    <ul>
        <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
            <li id="recordsArray_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['content']; ?></li>  
        <?php endWhile; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also, there should always be at least one linebreak/whitespace between the `<?php` and `?>` tags to the code.

Comment: Or just put some spaces into his existing code...

Comment: True, though it still gives it a better more readable look.

Answer (score 1):

Маке

```
<?php}?>
```

to

```
<?php } ?>
```

This should fix the problem. You also have a `{?>` which you should change to `{ ?>`

Answer (score 0):

This has a few examples:

http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/php_with_html.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="contentLeft"> <ul>
     <?php
         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){?>
         <li id="recordsArray_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['content']; ?></li>  
     <?php }?> </ul> </div>
```

You need whitespace after

Answer (score 0):

Add some whitespace around your curly braces and that specific error will go away. (e.g. change `{?>` to `{ ?>` and `<?php}?>` to `<?php } ?>`